# toshiba satellite l350-17p

Tags: toshiba-satellite, toshiba

I am totally new on Linux and I want to use my old laptop toshiba satellite l350-17p to install Ubuntu 64 as the only OS on this machine. Do you think I am ok with the 64 or should Igo for the 32? Thank you and Regards

Answer (score 0):

According to the specification page from Toshiba for that computer, it uses an Intel Pentium T3400 processor. This processor (according to the Intel page [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/35583/Intel-Pentium-Processor-T3400-1M-Cache-2_16-GHz-667-MHz-FSB-Socket-P)) is of a 64-bit architecture. If your computer has 2 or more Gb of RAM, the 64-bit version of Ubuntu (or derivatives) is (are) recommended and will run quite well. If you have less than 2Gb of RAM,then the 32-bit version will involve a significant enough reduction in memory overhead that it will run better on your machine than the 64-bit version.

TL;DR:
your computer can run either, but if you have less than 2Gb of RAM use the 32-bit version. Else, use the 64-bit version.